# Tengo dos bucles WHILE y se salta el segundo

Tags: c++, while, bucles

Estoy intentando hacer un programa para el cual necesito almacenar diferentes valores en dos vectores. Para leer los valores uso dos bucles WHILE iguales, pero el del segundo vector se lo salta. ¿Qué le pasa?

El objetivo final es ver si un vector es prefijo del otro, ejemplo: {1,3,4,5,7} y {1,3,4} saldría true.

```
vector<int> vecA, vecB, small, large;
int elem;
int elem2, in = 0;
string prefix = "true";
std::cout << "Enter numbers for the first vector: " << std::endl;
while (std::cin >> elem)        // read until end-of-file or cin read invalid data input
    vecA.push_back(elem);
std::cout << "Enter numbers for the second vector: " << std::endl;
while (std::cin >> elem2)       // read until end-of-file or cin read invalid data input
    vecB.push_back(elem2);
if (vecA.size() < vecB.size()) {
    small = vecA;
    large = vecB;
}
else {
    large = vecA;
    small = vecB;
}
for (auto &r : small) {
    if (r != large[in]) { prefix = "false"; break; }
    in++;
}

std::cout << "Prefix is " << prefix << std::endl;
```

Comment: estas seguro de que se salta el bucle? o más bien nunca llega a la instrucción del mismo?

Comment: Sí, se lo salta, ya que el programa corre hasta el final y si debuggeo se ve como se lo salta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer bucle se ejecuta hasta que la lectura falla, es decir, hasta que introduces un caracter que no puede ser convertido a número. Después pretendes que se repita un segundo bucle que hace exactamente lo mismo... pero éste no se ejecuta ni una sola vez.

Cuando una lectura falla (para salir del primer bucle), los datos erróneos no son eliminados del *stream*, y tiene sentido... ¿Cuántos caracteres se deben descartar exactamente? ¿uno? ¿dos quizás? ¿Hasta el salto de línea? ¿?

Es tu responsabilidad limpiar el buffer y para ello tienes que hacer dos cosas:

1. Limpia los flags de error, `cin` estará bloqueado hasta que no se haga esto:

   ```
   std::cin.clear();
   ```
2. Elimina los caracteres que no te sirven. Para ello lo habitual es descartar todo lo que haya hasta el primer salto de línea:

   ```
   std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
   ```

   `numeric_limits` es una plantilla, en este caso `max()` devuelve el número más alto que puedes almacenar en un `int`. Lo que hace `ignore` en este caso es eliminar tantos caracteres como marca el primer parámetro, salvo que antes se encuentre un salto de línea, en cuyo caso lo descarta y detiene el bucle de limpieza.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)